# How to use mouse event to do AJAX call only if user is idle for X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, time, mouseevent

Apologies if this is a repost. I have seen many examples. But I can't seem to put together my needs.
I have a "today" page which displays all groups. Throughout the day more and more groups will appear. I want to be able to dynamically update these groups if the user has the page open and hasn't moved the mouse for X seconds. I have this chunk of code:

```
var timeout = null;
    j$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
        if (timeout !== null) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            //calls another page to check if there's new data to display. if so, wipe existing data and update
            j$.ajax({
                  url: "/include/new_Groups.php",
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(data){
                      j$( ".group_Container_Main" ).append( data ).fadeIn('slow');
                  }
                })
                  .done(function( html ) {
              });
        }, 3000);
    });
```

What this is doing is if the user hasn't moved the mouse after 3 seconds, do an AJAX call to update the group. This semi works. If you don't move the mouse, it will update. But it won't update again unless the mouse is moved and idle again for 3 seconds which is not good user experience.

I'm trying to find a way to just continually update the page every 3 seconds (for this example) if the user is idle. But if he's moving the mouse, there is to be no updating. Please ask questions if I'm unclear! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be straigh forward, use an interval and a function call instead

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var timer;

    $(window).on('mousemove', function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(update, 3000);
    }).trigger('mousemove');

    function update() {
        $.ajax({
            url    : "/include/new_Groups.php",
        }).done(function (html) {
            $(".group_Container_Main").append(html).fadeIn('slow')
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tLb3c3mj/)

**EDIT:**

To solve the issue of stacking ajax requests if for some reason they take more than three seconds to complete, we can just check the state of the previous ajax call before starting a new one, if the state is `pending` it's still running.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var timer, xhr;

    $(window).on('mousemove', function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(update, 1000);
    }).trigger('mousemove');

    function update() {
        if ( ! (xhr && xhr.state && xhr.state == 'pending' ) ) {
            xhr = $.ajax({
                url    : "/include/new_Groups.php",
            }).done(function (html) {
                $(".group_Container_Main").append(data).fadeIn('slow')
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Wont that stack AJAX call if the mouse is idle? The AJAX may not be finished when the second interval is called.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - It might, but if it's not finished in three seconds, it probably never will.

Comment: @adeneo I looked at the console, even while the mouse is moving it's still spitting out "update". Only when the mouse is idle should it spit out "update" if that makes sense.

Comment: @AkiraDawson - works for me, you did of course move the mouse over the lower right window in the fiddle ?

Comment: @adeneo Thank you very much. You really got me out of a pickle. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can invert your timer idea to this logical connection...

1. Set a timer for 3 seconds after which you will do the AJAX call
2. If the mouse is moved, reset the timer for 3 seconds

You now have a three second timer running whether or not the mouse is moved and you reset it on mouse move to get the behaviour you want in respect of only updating on idle.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(update, 3000);

function update() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    //calls another page to check if there's new data to display. if so, wipe existing data and update
    j$.ajax({
          url: "/include/new_Groups.php",
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
              j$( ".group_Container_Main" ).append( data ).fadeIn('slow');
          }
        }).done(function(html) {

        }).always(function() {
              timeout = setTimeout(update, 3000);
       });
}

j$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(update, 3000);
});
```

Comment: It will be better to reset `timeout` in `.always`, not in `.done`. So that one error will not break updating.

Comment: Very good point - else it would stop forever on a failure. I have updated.

Answer (score 1):

On the AJAX parameter, use the `complete` option to trigger a mouse move :

```
j$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (timeout !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = null;
        //calls another page to check if there's new data to display. if so, wipe existing data and update
        j$.ajax({
              url: "/include/new_Groups.php",
              cache: false,
              success: function(data){
                  j$( ".group_Container_Main" ).append( data ).fadeIn('slow');
              },
              complete: function(data){
                  j$(document).trigger('mousemove');
              }
            })
              .done(function( html ) {
          });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()` to make a repeating event.

I would call `setInterval()` outside of your event handler code, and then make your event handler code update a `lastTimeMouseMoved` (or something) timestamp, which would be checked by the code passed to your `setInterval()` call.

So, your code might look like this:

```
const IDLE_TIME = 3000;
var lastTimeMouseMoved = Date.now();

timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(Date.now() - lastTimeMouseMoved >= IDLE_TIME) {
        //calls another page to check if there's new data to display. if so, wipe existing data and update
        j$.ajax({
            url: "/include/new_Groups.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                j$( ".group_Container_Main" ).append( data ).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        })
            .done(function( html ) { });
    } // end idle if
}, IDLE_TIME);

j$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    lastTimeMouseMoved = Date.now();
});
```

Comment: @Regent Oh yeah, forgot that.